# How autocopy (on each save action) file in Intellij Idea to other directory?

Tags: javascript, java, html, maven, intellij-idea

I have java project with `html`/`js` files. These files are packaged by `maven` and deployed to `Java EE` application server.

To modify one symbol I (theoretically) need to recompile, repackage and redeploy whole project. In practice change `html`/`js` in `Intellij Idea` project and copy them directly to application server manually.

May be `Idea` support automatically coping files on save action?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `IDEA Ultimate` (paid) edition, it supports creating Run/Debug configurations for application servers.

This allows you to create, deploy your application and test/debug within `IDEA`, without building with `Maven`.

For example, if you use `Tomcat`:

[image]

Once you launch this configuration, you'll get a convenient `redeploy` button.